# Redirecting to Other Pages after Logging In

Tags: asp.net

In my web application, I have 2 users and 2 roles. I want to redirect the users to different pages based on the roles.

I used the following code to Login_LoggedIn event handler:

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(Login.UserName,"Member"))
      Response.Redirect("~Protected/frmMemberHome.aspx");
else if(Roles.IsUserInRole(Login.UserName,"Admin"))
      Response.Redirect("~Admin/frmAdminPanel.aspx");
```

Now, this doesn't work for me. the event don't fire itself. In my case, after successful logging only the Login page is refreshed automatically and absolutely nothing happens.

Some of the forums on the Internet suggests to set the DestinationPageURL property of the Login Control of ASP.NET, but my problem is I can not redirect all users to the same URL, I need to change the DestinationPageURL based on roles.

this is my UserLogin page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mainLayout.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmUserLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnlineTMS_MIST.frmUserLogin" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Login ID="Login" runat="server"
        DisplayRememberMe="False">
</asp:Login>
    </asp:Content>
```

I have no idea, what to do. Whatever other forums suggested is the same thing I tried before but not worked for me.

Comment: The code should work. Just got to see why the LoggedIn event is not firing.

Comment: may this post can help you http://forums.asp.net/p/1458476/3345327.aspx

Comment: i have no idea, why it is not firing...

Comment: @naimshaikh, i didn't customize anything, login control has no CommandName property

Comment: can u provide you asp:html code and c# code

Comment: @naimshaikh..HTML code of Login page is given...

Comment: In which event handler are you putting in your redirect code ?

Comment: I don't see OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" there

Comment: @BeenishKhan...I am putting my code in Login_LoggedIn event handler

Comment: @naimshaikh Thanks brother. It perfectly works...Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare your login control markup and mine.

```
<asp:Login ID="Login" runat="server"
        DisplayRememberMe="False">
</asp:Login>
```

it's mine:

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe ="true" 
            onloggedin="Login1_LoggedIn">
        </asp:Login>
```

I think you have not bind the event with the event handler. this section is missing `onloggedin="Login1_LoggedIn"` in your markup. If you have done it on Page_Init event as:

```
 Login1.LoggedIn +=new EventHandler(Login1_LoggedIn);
```

Firtly check this and update whether it working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try using....

```
string RoleName = Roles.GetRolesForUser("username");
if(RoleName = "Member")
   Response.Redirect("~/Protected/frmMemberHome.aspx");
else if(RoleName = "Admin"))
   Response.Redirect("~/Admin/frmAdminPanel.aspx");
```